# Discord.JS TypeError: message.author.hasPermission is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was working on a command for a discord.js bot, and whilst making a `command` command (which turns commands on/off), I've been encountering errors.

When I use the `.hasPermission` function, I get the error encountered in the title:

`TypeError: message.author.hasPermission is not a function`

I do not believe it's a problem with my code, as the constructor works on other commands, but I'm open to suggestions. My code is below:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'module',
    description: 'Turn commands on/off',
    execute(message, args) {
        // required
        const Discord = require('discord.js');
        const db = require('quick.db')
        var randomExt = require('random-ext');
        //required end

        var commands = ['changelog','invite','prefix','balance','bankrob','beg','deposit','gamble','job','rob','work','afk','avatar','botinfo','serverinfo','userinfo','level','setlevel','ban','kick','mute','purge','unban','unmute','warn','warnings']
        let user = message.author;
        let commandSelect;
        
        const permissionEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('You dont have permission to do this')

        const commandFail = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('There is no command with that name!')

        const argsError = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Usage: `command <command> <on/off>`')
        
        const completeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`Command \`${args[0]}\` is now \`${args[1]}\``)
        
        if (!message.author.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
            return message.channel.send(permissionEmbed);
        } else if (user.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
            if (!args[0] || !args[1]) {
                return message.channel.send(argsError);
            } else if (args[0] != 'on' && args[0] != 'off') {
                return message.channel.send(argsError);
            }
            for (i = 0; i > commands.length; i++) {
                if (args[0] == commands[i]) {
                    return commandSelect = commands[i];
                }
            }
            if (commandSelect = null || commandSelect == undefined) {
                return message.channel.send(commandFail);
            } else {
                db.set(`${message.guild.id}.${commandSelect}`, 'false')
                return message.channel.send(completeEmbed);
            }
        }
    },
};
```

I also think it's worth mentioning that when I run the command with arguments, `p!command ban off`, I get the error `TypeError: Discord.MessasgeEmbed is not a constructor` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message.author` returns a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) and `message.member` returns a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember); the author of the message as a guild member.

Discord `User`s don't have permissions, guild `member`s have. You can only check if a member has certain permissions, so you need to change your code to:

```js
if (!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
  return message.channel.send(permissionEmbed);
}

// you don't need else or else if as this part is only executed if member
// is an administrator
if (!args[0] || !args[1]) {
  return message.channel.send(argsError);
} else if (args[0] != 'on' && args[0] != 'off') {
  return message.channel.send(argsError);
}
// ...
```